# I cannot get Circle-Stroke to work on Wordpress but will work fine on CodePen

Tags: wordpress, mapbox, geometry, codepen

I've set up a simple page here www.livehazards.com/animation-test

It won't recognise circle-stroke-color or circle-stroke-width on wordpress.....Yet I put the same code into codepen and codepen will run it fine

Anyone know what is going on??? Thanks

Here is the code

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
      <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8' />
      <title>Interactive Earthquake Live Map</title>
     <meta name="description" content=" Live real time maps of Earthquakes, 
      Volcanoes, Lightning and Storms across the world" />
    <link 
     href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
     rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-
    scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.26.0/mapbox-
     gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.26.0/mapbox-
     gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0%; bottom:0%; left:0%; width:100%; }
       .mapboxgl-popup-content {padding:10px; background:rgba(54, 69, 79, 0.8); 
      color:#fff; pointer-events:none;}
      </style>
   </head>
      <body>
     <div id='map'></div>
      <script>
            mapboxgl.accessToken ='pk.eyJ1IjoiaHlkcmFpZGVzIiwiYSI6ImNpdTFtMWx0MjAwMGIydHA4YnYyM2FteWgifQ.7Ox9rOJrv2p07vREPK2XFw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: [ 2.35, 48.85 ],
    zoom: 3
});

map.on('load', function() {
    map.addSource("earthquakes", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_day.geojson",
    });
map.addLayer({
        "id": "earthquake-layer",
        "type": "circle",
        "source": "earthquakes",
        "paint": {
            "circle-color": {
             property: 'mag',
                    stops: [
                        [3, '#fed976'],
                        [4, '#fd8d3c'],
                        [5, '#ff0000'],
                        [6, '#830300'],
                        [9, '#b10026'],
]
                },
             "circle-opacity": 0.6,
            "circle-stroke-width": 1,
          "circle-stroke-color": "#000",
            "circle-blur": 0.1,
            "circle-radius":50,
        },
    })
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry the page link is : http://livehazards.com/lightning/animation-test/

Answer (score 0):

Like your code snippet, the link you've provided is both using mapboxgl version 0.26. However, on livehazards, it's not using [`circle-stroke-color`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-circle-circle-stroke-color) or [`circle-stroke-width`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-circle-circle-stroke-width)

Very strange that you noticed it works on CodePen (maybe you're using the compatible mapbox version)
To use [`circle-stroke-color`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-circle-circle-stroke-color) or [`circle-stroke-width`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-circle-circle-stroke-width) you need mapboxgl version 0.29 or greater.

Use `https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.js`, and it will work :)